# Creating a pizza app using VB

Tags: vb.net

I am creating an app for a pizza restaurant. I have created code (BELOW) that will calculate the subtotal, total and vat when orders are selected and added up. The more you pay the greater the discount you obtain. But unfortunately I don't know what am doing wrong as it comes back as "InvalidCastExpectation was handled". Here is my code:

```
    Dim Total As Double
    Dim TotalProducts As Integer
    Dim Vat As Decimal = 0


    For Each Str As String In ListBox5.Items
        Total = Total + Str <<<<<< ( this section is the problem)

    Next
    TextBox9.Text = FormatCurrency(+Total)
    For Each Str As String In ListBox1.Items
        TotalProducts = TotalProducts + CInt(Str)

    Next
    Total = Total = CDbl(Total)
    TextBox6.Text = Format(Total, "0.00")
    TextBox7.Text = Format(20 / 100 * TextBox7.Text)
    TextBox6.Text = Format(+Total + TextBox7.Text)
    Select Total
        Case Is < 10
            TextBox6.Text = Format(Total, "")
            TextBox8.Text = Format(20 / 100 * TextBox6.Text)
            TextBox6.Text = Format(+Total + TextBox7.Text)
        Case Is < 20
            MessageBox.Show("10% discount awarded")
            Total = (Total - (Total * 10 / 100))
            TextBox6.Text = Format(+Total)
            TextBox6.Text = Format(Total, "")
            TextBox8.Text = Format(20 / 100 * TextBox6.Text)
            TextBox8.Text = Format(+Total + TextBox7.Text)
```

Comment: `.Text` is a string, but you treat it as a number.  Those "Text" properties should be converted into the numerical types.  Same thing for your Str variable.  Use the decimal type for precision, not double.  Use [Decimal.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) to make sure you have valid input from the user.  Give your controls meaningful names.  TextBox6 and TextBox7 don't tell us anything about their contents.

Comment: Total is a double and str is a string. You have to convert it to a number first, before you can add it to total

Comment: Thanks for the input people. Am making the necessary corrections.

Comment: You really need to turn on Option Strict. Trying to perform math operations on text variables is a recipe for disaster.  After option strict is turned on and the MANY errors are highlighted - Use google to learn about type conversion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a whack at reformatting and cleaning up your code. There are a few questions you might think about:

How do you want to round your discount total, what should 12.333 or 12.338 total with a discount be?

How should VAT be rounded?

A big pointer that was mentioned by others is ALWAYS use decimal data type when working with currency. double values can change with the same input values from each time it is run, usually this happens at a low decimal value but it is still there and can bite you.

```
Private Sub TotalOrder()

Dim total As Decimal = 0
Dim totalProducts As Integer = 0
Dim totalWithVAT As Decimal = 0
Dim vat As Decimal = 0
Dim bDiscountGiven As Boolean = False

For Each sPrice As String In lbItemTotal.Items 'ListBox5.Items
    If IsNumeric(sPrice) Then
        total += CDec(sPrice)
    End If
Next


For Each sCount As String In lbItemCount.Items 'ListBox1.Items
    If IsNumeric(sCount) Then
        totalProducts += CInt(sCount)
    End If
Next

If total >= 10 Then
    total = Math.Round(total * 0.9D, 2)
    bDiscountGiven = True
End If

txtTotal.Text = FormatCurrency(total) ' TextBox9
vat = Math.Round(total * 0.2D, 2)
totalWithVAT = total + vat

txtVAT.Text = vat.ToString("0.00") 'TextBox7.Text
txtTotalWithVAT.Text = totalWithVAT.ToString("0.00") 'TextBox7.Text

If bDiscountGiven Then
    MessageBox.Show("10% discount awarded")
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look and modifying my code, I truly appreciate that. However the "total += CDec(sPrice)" seems to be a problem and i have tried to find what the problem but to no avail.in reference to your question bout  VAT, If the VAT comes to 0.5 of one penny or more, it should be rounded up i believe.

Comment: total += CDec(sPrice) would fail if sPrices is not a numeric string ie: "" emoty string, null, contains a non number character, or the number characters have a space between digits. you can do a check like "If IsNumeric(sPrice) then total += CDec(sPrice) end IF

Comment: I added IsNumeric checks and rounded the VAT

Answer (score 0):

The statement 
  `Total = Total + Str`

is trying to add a double value (like 15.11) with a string value that could be ABC123 or Null.

Try at least changing the "+ Str" to "+ CDbl(Str)", but really you should be using the [Double.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) to safely do so before adding the value.

Comment: Thank you .Makes sense. I will try as you suggested.